# How to INSERT or UPDATE depending on the result of SELECT in 1 statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, upsert

I'm trying to create an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement depending on the result of a `SELECT` statement in one go.

Currently, I have this statement that doesn't work:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET CQuantity = CQuantity + 1 
WHERE CBarcode = '00029218' 
  AND COALESCE(COUNT(SELECT CQuantity 
                     FROM Inventory 
                     WHERE CBarcode = '00029218'), 0) > 1;
```

Based on the SQL statement, it's supposed to update the quantity in the inventory table if the barcode is the specified value and if it finds an existing row in the inventory table. It doesn't work though.

I would like to `UPDATE` quantity if it finds an existing row in the inventory table, otherwise, it would `INSERT` a new row if barcode doesn't exist.

Thank you so much.

Comment: take a look at [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: MERGE is just syntactic sugar, and won't be atomic without appropriate locking (and has had more bugs than just about anything in SQL Server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard UpSert. Your logic should look like this.

```sql
DECLARE @barcode varchar(30) = '00029218';

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE Inventory WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
SET CQuantity += 1
WHERE CBarcode = @barcode;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT Inventory (CBarcode, CQuantity)
    VALUES (@barcode, 1);

COMMIT;
```

Take a read of [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern), and note the following:

- You need a transaction to ensure consistency.
- You need to add `UPDLOCK` and `HOLDLOCK/SERIALIZABLE` hints to ensure correct locking.
- You don't need to check first using a `SELECT`, it's wasteful. Just do the `UPDATE`, and if the `@@ROWCOUNT` is 0 then do the `INSERT`.
- You can swap around the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` if the latter is more likely.
- Don't use `MERGE` in SQL Server if you have a choice, it's full of bugs.

Comment: I'm using OUTPUT INSERTED.CQuantity inside the UPDATE statement to get the updated value of CQuantity. However, how do I OUTPUT the Inserted value CQuantity if INSERT is executed? I tried putting OUTPUT too inside the insert statement and it returns nothing if @@ROWCOUNT = 0. Thank you.

Comment: `INSERT Inventory (CBarcode, CQuantity) OUTPUT inserted.CQuantity VALUES (@barcode, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Try to write maintainable and easily readable code. No one ever complained because they could understand it! For a slightly less readable but more optimized method see @Charlieface's answer.

```
SELECT @Exists = CQuantity FROM Inventory WHERE CBarcode = '00029218'

BEGIN
IF @Exists > 0 THEN
    UPDATE Inventory SET CQuantity = CQuantity + 1 WHERE CBarcode = '00029218'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Inventory (CBarcode, CQuantity) VALUES ('00029218', 1)
END IF
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand makes some strong points against this pattern https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern

Comment: Yeah I do admire your way, in likely more than half scenarios you only do one dB hit.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you so much Sir! I understand your code and I'll give you a thumbs up but I'll choose the first answer because it's more complete. Thank you!

Comment: Thats not valid T-SQL, the `BEGIN` is hanging, and `END IF` isn't a thing.

Comment: Consistent casing, formatting and indenting go a long way to making a query readable and understandable :)